# Where is such a regex wrong？

Tags: python, regex

I am using python. 
The pattern is:

```
re.compile(r'^(.+?)-?.*?\(.+?\)')
```

The text like:

```
text1 = 'TVTP-S2(xxxx123123)'

text2 = 'TVTP(xxxx123123)'
```

I expect to get **TVTP**

Comment: How do you expect to get that? Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: Since `-` is optional, the first group will just match the first letter because it's not greedy, then `.*?` will match everything until `(`.

Comment: Use `r'^[^(\s-]+'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option to match those formats is:

```
^([^-()]+)(?:-[^()]*)?\([^()]*\)
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `([^-()]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times any character other than `-` `(` and `)`
- `(?:-[^()]*)?` As the `-` is excluded from the first part, optionally match `-` followed by any char other than `(` and `)`
- `\([^()]*\)` Match from `(` till `)` without matching any parenthesis between them

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ItuJT/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gtouGQ)

*Example*

```
import re

regex = r"^([^-()]+)(?:-[^()]*)?\([^()]*\)"
s = ("TVTP-S2(xxxx123123)\n"
    "TVTP(xxxx123123)\n")
    
print(re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

*Output*

```
['TVTP', 'TVTP']
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex works:

```
pattern = r'^([^-]+).*\(.+?\)'
>>> re.findall(pattern, 'TVTP-S2(xxxx123123)')
['TVTP']
>>> re.findall(pattern, 'TVTP(xxxx123123)')
['TVTP']
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick answer will be

```
^(\w+)(-.*?)?\((.*?)\)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/wL4jKe/2/

Answer (score 0):

It is because the first plus is lazy, and the subsequent dash is optional, followed by a pattern that allows any character.

This allows the regex engine to choose the single letter T for the first group (because it is lazy), choose to interpret the dash as just not being there, which is allowed because it is followed by a question mark, and then have the next .* match "VTP-S2".

You can just grab non-dashes to capture, followed by nonparentheses up to the parentheses.

```py
p=re.compile(r'^([^-]*?)[^(]*\(.+?\)')
p.search('TVTP-S2(xxxx123123) blah()').group(1)
```

The nonparentheses part prevents the second portion from matching 'S2(xxxx123123) blah(' in my modified example above.